# Are Gradle Resolvers available to Ant?

Tags: ant, gradle

I have an Ivy resolver defined in my `repositories` closure:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        name "local-ivy"
        url "http://host/ivy-repo/"
        layout 'pattern', { ... }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use it in an Ant publish task like this:

```
ant.taskdef(name: 'ivyPublish', classname: 'org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPublish', classpath: configurations.ivy.asPath)
ant.ivyPublish(pubrevision: '1.0.0',
               status: 'release',
               resolver: 'local-ivy',
               artifactspattern: 'buildSrc/ivyUpload/[artifact].[ext]',
               overwrite: true)
```

But I get the following exception when Ant tries to resolve a dependency:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown resolver local-ivy
```

Is it possible to expose my Gradle-defined resolver to Ant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared a resolver, but an Ivy repository. You can't use that on the Ant side. (Note that Gradle doesn't use the Ivy library anymore for accessing Ivy repositories.)